# Zero-width non-breaking space

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of text and at the end I want to insert two icons.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris <img ...><img ...>
```

I want to keep the two images joined and if an image overflows both should go to the new line, so what I need is something like a `&nbsp;` but with zero width.

Is there an html entity to do that or another way to archieve this without using a wrapper?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The No-Break Space is very similar to a Word-Joiner, just as it's very similar to a Space.  But each, has very different usages.  All of these variations exist to represent different widths and functions of a space character.

- U+00A0 **No-Break Space** `&nbsp;` represented similarly to a space character, it prevents an automatic line break.
- U+2007 **Figure Space** `&#8199;` a space somewhat equal to the figures (0–9) characters.
- U+202F **Narrow No-Break Space** `&#8239;` or `&nnbsp;`) used to separate a suffix from a word stem without indicating a word boundary.  Approximately 1/3 the representative space of a normal space though it may vary by font.
- U+2060 **Word-Joiner** `&#8288;` representative by no visible character, it prohibits a line break at its position.

#### Other No-Break Characters

- NON-BREAKING HYPHEN (U+2011)
- FIGURE SPACE (U+2007)
- NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F)
- TIBETAN MARK DELIMITER TSHEG BSTAR (U+0F0C)

---

W3C recommends using the Word-Joiner whenever you need to connect two characters or words so that they do not wrap. <sup>**[1]**</sup>

> To get the same functionality, formerly provided through the ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE authors should use a WORD JOINER (U+2060) instead

However, nowhere in the HTML4 Character Reference is <kbd>Word-Joiner</kbd> mentioned. <sup>**[2]**</sup>

> In addition to these characters the <kbd>SOFT HYPHEN (U+00AD)</kbd> can be used to provide line-break hints within words that UAs might not have in their own hyphenation dictionaries.

The only characters that are explicitly discouraged are <kbd>ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (U+200C)</kbd>: prevents ligation and cursive connections between characters that would other wise ligate or join cursively.

- <kbd>ZERO WIDTH JOINER (U+200D)</kbd>: encourages ligation and cursive connections.

---

#### References:

1. [W3C Wiki: HTML Character Usage](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/HTMLCharacterUsage#head-77638abc13541d600a7972b79038f55a0ad8de81_Separators_and_joiners)
2. [Character entity references in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)

---

#### Further:

1. [Unicode.org Correction of Word_Break Property Value for U+00A0 NBSP](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2006/06115-wordbreak.txt)
2. [Unicode v.3.2.0 Line Break Properties](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.2-Update/LineBreak-3.2.0.txt)
3. [Unicode ?Proposed? Line Breaking Properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-12.html)
4. [Unicode v7 Complete Standards](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/)
5. [Unicode Explained by Jukka Korpela](https://books.google.com/books?id=lxndiWaFMvMC&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=word+joiner+vs+no+break+space&source=bl&ots=Nctt5IW7IB&sig=Lge2gaBHGTjES4anyGEdEplHkDw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NW3YVPSAOsyoogT0oILYAQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=word%20joiner%20vs%20no%20break%20space&f=false_)

Comment: Very useful. This should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: Never heard of the word-joiner character (&#8288;)! +1

Comment: `U+2060 Word-Joiner &#8288; representative by no visible character`   This character is being rendered as a visible space in browsers.

Comment: Chrome does not recognize &nnbsp; and treats &#8239; in the same way as &nbsp;. But &#8288; seems to be handled properly.

Comment: For anyone wondering why none of these work, in the context of the problem stated in the question, despite this being the accepted answer: the clue is in the answer by Jukka K. Korpela. The `<img>` tags are not words, so browsers don't apply line/word breaking rules to them. As far as I know, there is currently no way of solving this problem that doesn't include wrapping the images in a separate, containing tag. In other words, the answer to the final question in the original post is: no, currently there is no way.

Answer (score 29):

There is no entity reference for ZWNBSP (zero-width no-break space) in HTML, but it, like any Unicode character, can be expressed using a character reference: `&#xfeff;` (or, equivalently, `&#65279;`). However, it is ineffective for keeping images in the same line. Images are not characters, and browsers are not required to implement Unicode semantics for ZWNBSP even when used between characters. The same applies to WORD JOINER, U+2060.

The most effective way is to wrap the `img` tags in a [`nobr` element](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#nobr): `<nobr><img ...><img ...></nobr>`. While not part of any HTML specification, and mentioned in HTML5 drafts as “obsolete”, this method works across browsers. If you would rather do things in a clumsier way that does not work when CSS is disabled, you can use an artificial wrapper element and set `white-space: nowrap` on it.

Comment: But there is: `&zwj;`, [since at least 2001](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-international/2001OctDec/0028.html)

Comment: @jthill, `&zwj;` denotes ZERO WIDTH JOINER U+200D, a different character, intended for requesting for cursive joining or ligature rendering.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the correction. I'll go read up on `&zwnj;` too.

Comment: ZWNBSP use as an indication of non-breaking is deprecated as of Unicode 3.2, use word joiner `&#x2060;` instead.

Comment: Using CSS is not clumsy.

Answer (score 15):

Try to wrap the images in a span with css property `white-space: nowrap;`:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><img ...><img ...></span>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was asking if there's any way to do that without a wrapper.

Comment: After testing other alternatives, this seems to be the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can go to this website: [Symbols](https://coolsymbol.com) - it provides easy access to many special symbols and characters. At the bottom of the page, you see a button for "Zero Width Space" character, just click on that button to have the "Zero Width Space" character copied in the clipboard.