# Line-break between tag and full stop

Tags: html, css

Using HTML and CSS, how can I avoid a line-break between the `span` and the `.` ?

HTML:

```html
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at convallis
    lorem, quis bibendum <span style="display: inline-block; color: red;">dolor</span>.
```

ACTUAL RESULT *ON CERTAIN VIEWPORT WIDTHS*:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Proin at convallis lorem, quis bibendum dolor
.
```

DESIRED RESULT ON ANY VIEWPORT WIDTH:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Proin at convallis lorem, quis bibendum dolor.
```

*PS: Put the `.` inside the `span` is not the answer I am looking for :)*

Here is a screenshot for the non-believers (note that I did remove a word from the example to get to the width where the issue occurs).

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173267/discussion-on-question-by-ben-line-break-between-tag-and-full-stop).

Comment: `&NoBreak;` ([word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner)) ought to be a solution, but [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392312/zero-width-non-breaking-space#comment133717065_28405917).

Answer (score 2):

Would pseudos be an option for you? *EDITED WITH POSITION*

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
span:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '.';
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: This will cause the `.` to be "inside" the `span`. Meaning if the `span` had, say, a `border`, then the `.` would be inside that border. So it's basically the same as just moving the `.` into the `span` element.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping it all up in a single span that doesnt wrap should work:

```
<span class="ext"><span>some long text</span>.</span>

span.ext {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Not if the text has multiple lines :(

Comment: @Ben How about `display:inline-block` on the element that contains the text?

Comment: In the OP, the text surely won't have multiple lines, since it has `inline-block` style, and OP is expecting full stop to appear right after.

Comment: On realization of this, I'd like to remove my upvote from the comment above, but [Stack Overflow won't allow me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/cancelling-upvote-on-comment).

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate an extra wrap element you can do

```css
span.wrap{white-space:nowrap;}
span.wrap span{
  display: inline-block; 
  color: red;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at convallis lorem, quis bibendum <span class="wrap"><span>dolor</span>.</span>
```

---

However in some comments i noticed you mentioned the scenario where you have a lot of text in the inner `span` which causes line breaks. In that case you have other problems besides the following period as an `inline-block` element that has line breaks internally will move as a block and not follow the previous word from it.

see

```css
span{
  display: inline-block; 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at convallis
    lorem, quis bibendum <span>dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab delectus sunt pariatur omnis, voluptatem vero accusantium rem a, est id nihil vitae cum impedit magnam itaque qui. Quaerat maxime numquam eveniet eaque possimus quos doloremque natus sit molestiae iste, autem, rerum facilis facere mollitia modi vel fuga non, tempore quibusdam.</span>.
```