# Is there any way to set the width of `&nbsp;` or `&nnbsp;` to zero?

Tags: html, css, non-breaking-characters

Is there any way to set the width of `&nbsp;` or `&nnbsp;` to zero?

EDIT: An answer from 11 years ago suggests that it is impossible, but perhaps CSS has gotten new features since then?

I am working with a font that has only a hyphen glyph and lacks a glyph for `em dash`. In order to simulate an em dash I wanted to concatenate two hyphens together with zero space between them and so that they also stay together during a wrap.  Is that possible?  At first I thought an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392312/zero-width-non-breaking-space) had the solution but the character that joins words `&#8288;` is rendered as a visible space.

I can wrap the `&mdash;` in a `span` and change the font with a CSS class, but I'm curious if it's possible to do anything with the non-breaking space.

P.S. I know that many other fonts have the em dash glyph, so I don't need to be given the very reasonable advice to change to a different font :-)

Comment: @DanielA.White   My only reservation is that it is from 11 years ago. CSS has gotten more features since then.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? https://330k.github.io/misc_tools/unicode_steganography.html