# Optional line-breaking HTML entity that is always invisible

Tags: html, line-breaks, html-entities

I want an optional line-breaking character that is always invisible that works with the `word-wrap: break-word;` CSS style.

Here are some specifics. My goal is to break apart long links in reasonable places. These characters are a good place to start: `-`, `.`, `_`, `/`, `\`. This is not a Rails-specific question, but I wanted to share some code I'm using now:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def with_optional_line_breaks(text)
    text.gsub(%r{([-._/\\])}, '\1&shy;')
  end
end
```

Here's the problem with the code above: when `&shy;` takes effect (in a table with: `word-wrap: break-word;`), `&shy;` gets displayed as `-`. I don't want to see the `-`; I want a line break without any character shown.

---

Comment: Does the simple <br> tag not work for you in this case?

Comment: @Christopher: `<br>` is not an optional line break

Comment: This answer might help. Not a character, but uses spans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`&#8203;` is the HTML entity for a unicode character called the zero-width space (ZWSP).

> "In HTML pages, this space can be used as a potential line-break in long words as an alternative to the `<wbr>` tag."- [Zero-width space - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

The `<wbr>` tag also works, as mentioned by [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841314/109618). I think I prefer the HTML entity over the tag because the entity seems simpler: unicode handles it, not the web browser.

Comment: Unicode handles it, but web browsers are not required to conform to the Unicode standard or to support this particular character. This is a tricky issue, but generally, ZWSP fails on fairly old browsers only, whereas `<wbr>` has oddities in newer browsers, too; see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html

Comment: @David, What about the invisible separator? See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm

Comment: @Pacerier This appears to be intended for mathematical whitespace, given the context of http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:subhead=Invisible%20operators:]. From http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm: "contiguity operator indicating that adjacent mathematical symbols form a list, e.g. when no visible comma is used between multiple indices".

Answer (score 14):

`<wbr>` looks like it does what you want, **but** it looks like the support for it, and `&shy;` for that matter, is [very inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227284/2603). So unfortunately, there may not be a particularly good way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. A note: the claim that browser support that is inconsistent is from 2008. On my system, modern browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome) do the right thing with `<wbr>`. I expect they also work for other word/line breaking methods. A comprehensive accounting can be found at [Soft hyphen (SHY) – a hard problem?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html)

Comment: Here's an answer providing a nice overview of the support of word-hyphenation/-breaking/-splitting techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672471/3439786
Furthermore there's also a _caniuse_ page: http://caniuse.com/#feat=wbr-element

Comment: One advantage of `<wbr>` over the zero-width space Unicode entity is that if the string you are wanting to break is a URL that might be copied from a browser (as when providing academic reference to a web page that isn't a link), the Unicode entity is copied (at least in MacOS) and the resulting URL looks correct in a browser but breaks when attempting to access it. `<wbr>` does not have this issue.

Comment: @DavidJ.   Here's an updated link for _[Soft hyphen (SHY) – a hard problem?](https://jkorpela.fi/shy.html)_

Answer (score 12):

I'll post this as an answer, in 2019, although it draws its substance entirely from other contributions on this page: use `<wbr>`. It works well in allowing the wrap of long URLs and so not having them break out of content boxes. Users being able to paste the link you show into a web browser does matter and support for `<wbr>` is good in modern browsers, according to caniuse.com and my own quick tests in Chrome and Firefox for Android. I replaced forward slashes with forward slashes and a WBR, URLs now wrapping nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, unicode is better than html tag. However, I prefer to use `&ZeroWidthSpace;` instead of `&#8203;` as its easy to comprehend in code.