# Defining word wrap breaking point

Tags: html, css

it's possible to define in css where should be the breaking point when a text begins to wrap?
for example, I have this text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

and I want to break this sentence in two only after "amet," like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit.

thanks

Comment: should every sentence break at that width?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break

Comment: For instance: http://jsbin.com/zojul/1/edit

Comment: Too bad it got closed, I had a working answer and was going to add it. The linked question is wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/428fevjq/1/

Comment: @CBauer It got closed because it is a duplicate question. The OP didn't want to break the line permanently (as you did by adding a `<br>` element next to `amet` word via jQuery!) but to specify the breaking point `when a text begins to wrap`.

Comment: I didn't see your jsbin until now, that's an even better answer then.