# Inline text in absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display text contained in a div which has a `position: absolute;` on only one line.

The parent is `position:relative;` and the width of the parent might be smaller than the div containing the text.

I would like the text of my `position: absolute;` div staying on one line, how could I achieve that? For the moment, the maximum width of the div is the width of the parent.

Here is a jsfiddle I made to explain the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/fb15mq68/

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: take a look at this question (has a lot of various answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break/35741496#35741496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent text wrapping with the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property:

- `white-space: nowrap`

  > Collapses whitespace as for `normal`, but suppresses line breaks (text
  >   wrapping) within text.
- `white-space: pre`

  > Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at
  >   newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

Probably, you want the first one.

```css
.box {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    This is the text I want to display inline
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also, using escape characters can work too, and they are more widely supported than anything. I give you my answer free to use in reference. Not a problem with me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break/35741496#35741496

Comment: I just don't want to have to repost it. Laziness, you know? plus extra kudos for you

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting, I didn't know all of that!