# Break responsive list in the middle

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a responsive menu, laid out as an unordered list. At larger sizes, it's inline and looks nice:
[image: Initial layout]
But as the window shrinks, it breaks and looks awkward:
[image: Responsive result]
Ideally, I'd like it to break evenly in half when it overflows, like this:
[image: Ideal result]
Using a `<wbr>` in the list doesn't seem to do anything and I'm out of ideas. [This question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break), which suggests using `inline-block`, works well for paragraphs but doesn't seem to work with lists.

Here's a CodePen example that demonstrates the breaking issue:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVoLov?editors=1100

Comment: Yes, good question - it should break in half when it overflows. I'll update the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html (+css): denoting a preferred place for a line break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break)

Answer (score 1):

You can change width with media queries to `33%` of each `li`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  li {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  li  {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Thing One</li>
    <li>Thing Two</li>
    <li>Thing Three</li>
    <!-- ideally, break here -->
    <li>Thing Four</li>
    <li>Thing Five</li>
    <li>Thing Six</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really nice simple solution. But (I think) it only works for 3- or 6-element lists (ie: looks weird if the list has 4 elements). Is it possible there's a more universal solution?

Comment: @JeffThompson I am not sure what you mean by `more universal solution`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with display:flex.

This is a great article about this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The flexbox are amazing but have problems with old browsers (internet explorer...). You can check the compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox