# Is there a notion of a preferentially breaking space in either HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

Let this would be the opposite of a non-breaking space, saying 'don't feel obliged to break this sentence, but if you do so, do it here first'.

For example, if in the above quote the space after 'sentence' were such a character, then on thinner screens it would break first like this:

'don't feel obliged to break this sentence,

but if you do so, do it here first'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392853/html-css-denoting-a-preferred-place-for-a-line-break?